# Laravel 7 - Bulk Insertion

Tags: php, laravel, checkbox, eloquent, insert

I'm trying to insert the selected data with checkboxes but when I submit the dat it throws me this error:

> Invalid argument supplied to foreach().

It worked before when I had the first foreach and the variable $consecutive_final

- My function that does the array insert of the selected checkboxes and request the data

```
 public function create(Request $request)
    {
        try {
            foreach ($request->get('student_id') as $index => $student_id) {
                foreach ($request->get('year') as $index => $year) {
                    foreach ($request->get('season') as $index => $season) {
                        foreach ($request->get('program') as $index => $program) {
                            foreach ($request->get('course') as $index => $course) {
                                foreach ($request->get('level') as $index => $level) {
                                    $consecutive = DB::select('SELECT SUM(certificationId) FROM certification GROUP BY certificationId');
                                    $final_consecutive = sprintf("%04d", $consecutive);
                                       
                                    DB::table('certification')->insert([
                                        'student_id' => $student_id,
                                        'consecutive' => $final_consecutive,
                                        'year' => $year,
                                        'season' => $season,
                                        'program' => $program,
                                        'course' => $course,
                                        'level' => $level,
                                    ]);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return back()->with('success', 'Constancia creada correctamente');
        } catch (\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e) {
            $message = $e->getMessage();
            if (strpos($message, "Duplicate entry")) {
                return back()->with('err', 'Esta constancia ya ha sido creada');
            }
            if (strpos($message, "1366 Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'idGrupo'")) {
                return back()->with('err', 'Debe seleccionar un grupo para poder continuar');
            }
            return back()->with('err', $message);
        }
    }
```

- And this is my form where the inputs don't actually ask for information, but I map it

```
<form action="{{url('/Create/Certification/')}}" method="POST">
                                {{csrf_field()}}

                                <td class="align-middle text-center">
                                <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" name="grade[]" 
                                value="{{isset($student->pivot->grade)?$student->pivot->grade:''}}" placeholder="grade" disabled>
                            </td>

                            <td class="align-middle text-center">
                            @foreach ($group->levels as $level)
                                <input type="hidden" value="{{ $nivel->course->program->season->year->year }}" id="year" name="year[]">
                                {{$level->course->program->season->year->year}}
                            @endforeach
                            </td>
                            <td class="align-middle text-center">
                            @foreach ($group->levels as $level)
                                <input type="hidden" value="{{ $level->course->program->season->seasonName }}" name="season[]">
                                {{$level->course->program->season->seasonName}}
                            @endforeach
                            </td>
                            <td class="align-middle text-center">
                            @foreach ($group->levels as $level)
                                <input type="hidden" value="{{ $level->course->program->programName }}" name="program[]">
                                {{$level->course->program->programName}}
                            @endforeach
                            </td>
                            <td class="align-middle text-center">
                            @foreach ($group->levels as $level)
                                <input type="hidden" value="{{ $level->course->courseName }}" name="course[]">
                                {{$level->course->courseName}}
                            @endforeach
                            </td>
                            <td class="align-middle text-center">
                            @foreach ($group->levels as $level)
                                <input type="hidden" value="{{ $level->levelName }}" name="level[]">
                                {{$level->levelName}}
                            @endforeach
                            </td>

                        

                                <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="hidden" name="student_id[]" value="{{$student->student_id}}" >

                                <td class="align-middle text-center">
                                    <input id="select" type="checkbox" name="select[]">
                                </td>
                        </tr>
                        @endif
                        @endforeach
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-success">Create</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Comment: Can you determine which `foreach` is it failing? Make sure you pass an array in the `foreach`. Also I don't any `anio` input on your form.

Comment: Ok, let me check it. Sorry, I forgot to translate that, it's the year.

Comment: Actually, I think that `year` array is the one that fails because when I tried another method, the error was that the `year` value doesn't have a default value. And when I printed the values ​​of the array the years are supposed to be 2022 but it gives me 29 and I don't know where that value comes from.

Comment: you can create a function that shuffles the arrays, it will be easier for debugging . Try it : https://onlinephp.io?s=jZLRSsMwFIavW8g7HCGQBUKHujudw4s9xSgS25QG17SkKZvI3t1z0laqouyioZzzf3_-nORx19UdS7kt-y0cWJrcqjt1rzYszR-w7HRjpobQQoF4paUQY5ul1eCKYFsHjT0_e7_i2nsFtO7PwWv8fTPvkqUfaMBD0wF6EZnYanVTtIMLEZESvAmDd9ANfb0_msZQB4FfZgoNJDlUrTe6qCMPugdujkYCbTTvdIVXhMjtgt8UgaRYunw737Ve41GX2aJmCrjId8hpFlmWEaYgIQ_YPpEq_zMQd-aEY56nuF6DLksgUthSLPvzfYwFDIcXrKJK_gDpiv9H4yNQk5LwzlsXXr4kVPoE&v=8.1.6

Comment: Ok, I'll check it.

Comment: It is the last foreach that is failing.

Comment: Now I have this error: `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'year' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `certifications` (`student_id`, `consecutive`) values (2022010023, 0000))`

Comment: Ok, now I've updated the code and it is inserting a lot of data into the database.